# Problem on Dropdown Broken layout in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I have a dropdown in my react app using styled-components. It works just as I expected on google chrome on windows. It should be on the top of the ellipsis button and some space to its right.
The problem is on the safari, it's being cut out to the right?

Pls check my code sandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/open-specific-menu-in-reactjs-forked-qfuzy?file=/src/Form.js)

```
const DropdownMenu = styled.span`
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: ${({ show }) => (show ? "block" : "none")};
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 141px;
  height: 100px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 7px 7px #00000029);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Forked your Sandbox and edited some of your properties. Now it works also on Safari. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/open-specific-menu-in-reactjs-forked-4spdp?file=/src/Form.js

I gave the Dropdown a position relative to the button (bottom: 100%; and right: 0). Now it knows where it should be.

```
const ButtonSection = styled.div`
  ...
  position: relative;
`;

const DropdownMenu = styled.span`
  ...
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
`;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you check there's a space below on the first dropdown? Its only also on safari.

Comment: If you want a space below your dropdown, you have to modify the bottom: 100% property. Example: bottom: calc(100% + 20px);

Comment: The first dropdown has a space below while the second dropdown doesn't have space below. They should be both the same, right?

Comment: I updated my codesandbox with the calc property. It works on my Mac on Chrome and Safari. Both dropdowns have 20px space at the bottom.

Comment: Ok thank you!!!. I just remove other properties from the `ButtonSection`.

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446086/broken-video-full-height-in-reactjs. Thank you.